# change image by multi value

Tags: jquery

I have created an HTML list using `span` tags. I would like to change the SRC of the image at the top to `image/' prefix and and the suffix taken from data-idName. For example, hovering over the first span would give:

```
image/baba-au-rhum1.jpg
```

Please tell me how I can acheive this.

```
<div>
    <img id="imgid" src="image/default.jpg" width="300" height="171" alt="Hello">
</div>

<div>
    <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 60px;">
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum1.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">la</span> for&ecirc;t noire</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum2.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">le</span> framboisier</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum3.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">l'</span> op&eacute;ra</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum4.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">le</span> flan nature</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum5.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">le</span> mille feuilles</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum6.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">l'</span> &eacute;clair au chocolat ou caf&eacute;</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum7.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">la</span> tarte Tatin</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum8.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">le</span> baba au rhum</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum9.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">le</span> financier a la framboise</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum10.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">la</span> tarte aux fraises</span>
            <br />
        <span id="hoverId" data-idName="baba-au-rhum18.jpg">
            <span class="classRed">l'</span> ile flottante &agrave; la cr&egrave;me</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to constant interruptions on my side, PapparazzoKid got here long before me. However, since I've been working on this since it was posted I will post what I came up with.

As PapparazzoKid mentioned, you cannot have two (or more) elements with the same ID attribute value. That's what classes are for -- just use classes instead.

I made the `alt` attribute change also so you can see the change take place in the fiddle. Note, too, that I changed all your IDs to `class="hoverClass"`. The rest of your code is as-is.

Here is a complete working example of what you have requested.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8dLy0yjf/1/)

```
var tmp;
$('.hoverClass').hover(
    function(){
        //hover IN
        tmp = 'image/' + $(this).attr('data-idName');
//        tmp = 'image/'+ $(this).data("idName");
        $('#imgid').attr('src',tmp).attr('alt',tmp);
    },
    function(){
        //hover OUT
    }
);
```

Comment: Updated fiddle with small change, fyi

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot have `hoverId` as the ID of all the span elements. Each element *must* have its own unique ID, like hover1, hover2, hover3, etc.

The jQuery would be:

```
$('span[data-idName]').hover(function() {
    var newURL = $(this).attr('data-idName');
    $('img#imgid').attr('src', 'image/' + newURL);
});
```

Comment: Thank you
If i like to add it to Joomla what's the URL will be?